# How to add/update/delete nested collections/documents using Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some nested `collections/docs` and I'm stuck how to handle that, I have 
*collection* `collection1` -> `documentionId` -> `documentationId2`.

[image]

I want to loop through `id` inside `ids` `documantiation1`.

**What I've tried:**

I'm tried to add it like this:

```
db.collection("news")
            .add(user)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {
                    documentReference.collection("ids");

                }
            })
```

But it's seems that I missing a lot.

Also I tried to get data like (For sure not what I want):

```
db.collection("news")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<PostsData> posts = new ArrayList<>();
                        List usersId = new ArrayList();
                        for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            PostsData postsData = new PostsData();


                            postsData.setBody(document.getString("body"));
                            postsData.setWriter(document.getString("by"));
                            postsData.setDate(String.valueOf(document.getData().get("time")));
                            postsData.setFromBook(document.getString("book"));
                            postsData.setVoteCount(String.valueOf(document.getData().get("rate")));
                            usersId.add(document.getString("id"));
                            postsData.setVotedUsers(usersId);
                            posts.add(postsData);

                        }
```

**Question:**

How to add/update/delete these nested collections/documents easily?

Comment: I hope I'm not stating the obvious but just to clarify: each subcollection is a separate instance owned by each specific `news` document. Your first example has a document just being added to `news`, it would not have anything in its subcollection `news` yet.